# How to prove the equality of two matrix expressions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am new to linear algebra and my question maybe too simple. I have a n-by-m matrix $D$ that its columns have unit L2 norm. Let $D_a$ be a sub-matrix of $D$ composed by some columns of $D$. I need to prove that the following equality is true:

$(D_a^TD_a)^{-1}D_a^T=(D_a^TD_a)^{-1}D_a^TD(D^TD)^{-1}D^T$

where the superscript $T$ denotes the matrix transpose. I have checked the correctness of this equality for randomly generated matrices with unit column norm in MATLAB.

Comment: The inverse of a matrix is defined only for square matices, so your question is not clear. If $D$ is a square matrix that $D_a$ is not square... So you have to better define your question or it has no sense.

Comment: As shown in above expressions, matrix inversion is applied on the $D^TD$ and $D_a^TD_a$ where both of them are square matrices.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we need the assumption that $D^TD$ and $D_a^TD_a$ are invertible.  This in turn implies that $m \leq n$ and that $D$ has full rank (i.e. rank $m$).

Applying $D_a^TD_a$ on both sides, we see that it is equivalent to prove that
$$
D_a^T=D_a^TD(D^TD)^{-1}D^T
$$
We note that for any $y \in \Bbb R^n$, there is a $x \in \Bbb R^m$
such that $y = Dx$. It follows that
$$
D_a^TD(D^TD)^{-1}D^T y
D_a^TD(D^TD)^{-1}D^T (Dx) = \\
D_a^TD(D^TD)^{-1}(D^T D)x = \\
D_a^T Dx = \\
D_a^T (Dx) = \\
D_a^Ty
$$
The equality follows.

Comment: If we assume that $m \le n$ , the relation $y=Dx$ denotes an overdetermined system which may not have a solution for $x$. Which condition on $D$ would gurantee the existance of $x$?